# Preview window functionality similar to StackOverflow tags

Tags: javascript, preview

I am trying to create an item preview(quickview) using javascript that changes it's orientation depending on the mouse position. I would like to have a functionality similar to the one existing in stackoverflow:

When an item is at the bottom of the page the preview window should change it's orientation(when the page is scrolled or browser window is resized). Currently it is shown below or above the cursor but it is not related to the actual cursor position(not related to the screen or browser window size). I am new to javascript and would appreciate any help.

Here is the code I am using as a starting point:

```
function AssignPosition(d) {

if(self.pageYOffset) {
    rX = self.pageXOffset;
    rY = self.pageYOffset;
    }
else if(document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
    rX = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    rY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
else if(document.body && document.body.scrollTop) {
    rX = document.body.scrollLeft;
    rY = document.body.scrollTop;
    }
if(document.all) {
    cX += rX; 
    cY += rY;
    }

var divHeight = d.style.height.replace(/px/, "");
divHeight = parseInt(divHeight);
if (cY < divHeight * 3 ) {
    d.style.left = (cX+50) + "px";
    d.style.top = (cY-10) + "px";
    }

else {
    cY = cY - divHeight;
    d.style.left = (cX+50) + "px";
    d.style.top = (cY-10) + "px";
    }
```

}